# Element type is invalid. Received a promise that resolves to: undefined. Lazy element type must resolve to a class or function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am using NextJS v14 with MUI v5. I have a home page that renders a news component. But I keep getting the error mentioned when I turn my component into a server component that fetches data from a server. I am sure that I am getting the data properly as I am able to log the data in the terminal and not in the browser. It appears that the issue happens when making the component async. But it is required to be able to get the data from the server. The news page itself (not component) works just fine with this approach, so I am genuinely confused.

src/app/page.tsx

```
import React from "react";
...

const App: FC<AppProps> = () => {
  return (
    <ConsumerLayout>
      <Box>
        <Box sx={{ height: "100%" }}>
          <Banners />
        </Box>
        <Box sx={{ display: "flex", width: "100%" }}>
          <Box sx={{ width: "50%" }}>
            <Weather />
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ width: "50%" }}>
            <News />
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </ConsumerLayout>
  );
};

export default App;
```

src/components/news.tsx

"If you remove the typography and grid components (including its children and must be both) it will start working"

```
import React from "react";
import { Box, Typography, Grid, Link } from "@mui/material";
import ErrorOutlineIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ErrorOutline";
import ArrowForwardIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowForward";
import NextLink from "next/link";
import NewsCard from "./news-card";
import fetchNews from "../apiConfig/server/news-api";

const News: React.FC = async () => {
  const { response, error } = await fetchNews();

  return (
    <Box>
      {response && (
        <Box
          sx={{
            width: "100%",
            p: "50px",
          }}
        >
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: "flex",
              width: "100%",
              justifyContent: "center",
              flexDirection: "column",
            }}
          >
            <Typography color="text.primary" variant="h3" sx={{ mb: "20px" }}>
              {"Latest News"}
              <Link
                color="text.primary"
                component={NextLink}
                href="/news"
              >
                <ArrowForwardIcon />
              </Link>
            </Typography>

            <Grid
              container
              spacing={2}
              sx={{
                maxHeight: "390px",
                overflowY: "scroll",
                scrollbarWidth: "none",
              }}
            >
              {response.data.map((item) => (
                <Grid item xs={12} sx={{ display: "flex" }} key={item.id}>
                  <NewsCard news={item} />
                </Grid>
              ))}
            </Grid>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      )}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default News;
```

src/components/news-card.tsx

```
"use client";

import React from "react";
import { Box, Button, Typography, styled } from "@mui/material";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import newsThumbnail from "../assets/images/news-thumbnail.svg";
import ScheduleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Schedule";
import CalendarTodayIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CalendarToday";
import { formatDateTime } from "../utils/date-time-formatter";
import type { CardComponentProps } from "../types/index";

const CardComponent: React.FC<CardComponentProps> = ({ news }) => {
  const { id, attributes } = news;
  const { title, publishedAt } = attributes;

  const router = useRouter();
  const ColorButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) => ({
    color: "#F3F4F6",
    backgroundColor: "#E5E7EB",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#F3F4F6",
    },
  }));

  return (
    <ColorButton
      id="id"
      sx={{
        borderRadius: "6px",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        p: "15px",
        alignContent: "left",
        alignItems: "left",
        width: "100%",
      }}
      onClick={() => {
        router.push(`/news/${id}`);
      }}
    >
    </ColorButton>
  );
};

export default CardComponent;
```